# Excel does not count "" as empty cell

Tags: excel

I use an IF statement to fill some cells. They are then conditionally formated based on if they are empty or not. This works fine for cells that get filled with `""` by the IF statement.
However now I want to count the cells that are not blank. I used `=CountIf(Range,"<>"&"")` This yields not the desired result. It gives a count of all the cells in the range, instead of only those cells that have actual text in them.

Comment: just `"<>"` instead of `"<>"&""`

Comment: What about `COUNTA`? I think this is to count non-empty cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner This also counts all cells that contain "", not only the cells that contain actual text.

Comment: @Moacir this also gives a count of all cells in the range.

Comment: As a check I just calculated the length of each cell. For all cells containing "" the lenght is 0, for other cells it is higher. Is there a way to use LEN in CountIF?

Comment: I know if you use "?" it counts everything with 1 character. "??" means 2 characters and so on

Comment: @Moacir, thanks for the hint. Combining with the wildcard it will work. Using "?*" it will count everything with 1 character or more. I also found another way: =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(RANGE)>0))

Comment: Note that `=CountIf(Range,"?*")` seems to count only text values, but `=SumProduct(--(Len(range)>0))` ( or `=SumProduct(Sign(Len(range)))` counts non-text values too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
=Countif(Range,"?*")
```

This will count everything that has 1 character or more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a truly empty cell and a cell containing a formula returning *Null*:

Null & Empty    `=COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)`
All but Empty   `=COUNTA(A1:A10)`
Empty only  `=ROWS(A1:A10)*COLUMNS(A1:A10)-COUNTA(A1:A10)`
Nulls only  `=COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)-(ROWS(A1:A10)*COLUMNS(A1:A10)-COUNTA(A1:A10))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however this does not result in being able to count the cells I described.

Comment: The use of "Null" seems kind of strange because cells that result in `""` are usually called Blank, and cells without formula are Empty. But I guess the idea of the answer is that All but Blank and Empty `=ROWS(A1:A10)*COLUMNS(A1:A10)-COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)`